# How to compute the length of line segments inside an isosceles trapezoid parallel to the base

Tags: geometry

[image]here is the problem in a picture, sorry for the drawing. i have found how to compute the midline of the isosceles trapezoid, 1/2 (top+bottom) , but there seems to be no formula for other line segments inside aside from the midline. I need to know the length of the x and y values in the photo. Thank you[image: this is the photo of the problem. sorry about the drawing.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the top line is $ \overline{AB}$ and the bottom line is $\overline{CD}$.
Now, find a point $E$ in $\overline{CD}$ such that $\overline{AE}$ is parallel to $\overline{BD}$. Then apply the rule for the ratio of similar triangles to the triangle $\overline{ACE}$.

[image: triangle]

Update: $$\frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{AC}{AE}=\frac{BC}{DE}$$ if $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADE$ are similar triangles.

Update 2: I forget to tell you another fact. If $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADE$ are similar triangles, 
$$\frac{\text{height of }\triangle ABC}{\text{height of } \triangle ADE}=\frac{AB}{AD}$$

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but how will it compute for the x and y values in the drawing? i had this link for reference http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/similar/triangles/side-splitter-theorem.php , but i still could not figure out how to solve for the needed values given that theorem..

Comment: I update the solution.

Comment: i dont think the solution fits the problem. the needed values are the line segments inside the isosceles trapezoid (please see second drawing). How will the law of similar triangles be applied to it? if i draw a parallel line AE parallel to BD, line segments x and y values could still not be computed

Comment: The line segment will become two parts. One part has same length as the top line. And you can apply law of similar triangles to Another part. Then you add them up.

Comment: but that would still not solve the issue. im not sure if you truly understand the problem or you are just trolling me..

Comment: @user2718969  I forget to tell another fact. See my update.